# Python generator function and permutations

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, generator, permutation

Problem input: two lists `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]`

Output: lists that begin with a permutation of `[1,2,3]` followed by a permutation of `[4,5,6]`

Example outputs are `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`, `[3,2,1,4,5,6]`, `[3,2,1,6,5,4]` etc. I want to loop through them using a generator.

I tried with the following script (Python3):

```
from itertools import permutations

def foo():
    perm_1 = permutations([1,2,3])
    perm_2 = permutations([4,5,6])

    for p1 in perm_1:
        for p2 in perm_2: 
            yield list(p1) + list(p2)

f = foo()

for ls in f:
    print(ls)
```

As outputs I get

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4]
```

As you can see, the permutations of the first list are never used and e.g output [3,2,1,4,5,6] is never produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that, once iterated, `perm2` will be empty.

So, on the first iteration of the outer `for` loop, everything is fine. On the following iterations, however, `perm2` will just be empty.

See a simpler example here:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> a = permutations([1,2,3])
>>> list(a)
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1)]
>>> list(a)
[]
```

To solve it, replace `perm_2` with `permutations([4,5,6])`

(Another solution could be to convert `perm_2` to a `list` when storing it but I think keeping everything with generators is more idiomatic)

Comment: I knew it was something embarrassingly simple!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
perm_1 = permutations([1,2,3])
perm_2 = permutations([4,5,6])
```

Once you load `permutations` this will never come again on you for loop.

try this instead and get each of them as a list:

```
perm_1 = list(permutations([1,2,3])) 
perm_2 = list(permutations([4,5,6]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's happening because itertool's permutation method is implemented as a generator function under the hood. Since you are using a nested for loop, with `p1 = (1, 2, 3)`, `perm_2` generates all the possible permutations of the numbers in the list `[4, 5, 6]` and becomes exhausted. It is not possible to iterate over generator functions/expressions more than once so thats why the loop just ends with only possible ordering from `perm_1`.